# How to dynamically create link to an individual email in Outlook web app when using the trigger 'When a new email arrives in a shared inbox (V2)'?

Tags: outlook, power-automate

When using the Power Automate trigger:

[When a new email arrives in a shared inbox (V2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#when-a-new-email-arrives-in-a-shared-mailbox-(v2))

I have access to the following message related variables:

```
Message ID
Internet Message ID
Conversation ID
```

How can I dynamically create a link so that users can click on it and go directly to the email?

I just need to know the format of the URL that will achieve the desired effect - I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to open the individual email, just the mailbox:

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail/shared_mailbox_email_address_here/inbox/id/conversation_id_here%3D
```

Comment: Try as i might, deeplinking with https://outlook.office.com/owa/?ItemID=[Message ID]&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem&path=&exvsurl=1
seems to work only with personnal mailbox every attempt with a shared mailbox fails Is there a parameter missing in the URL to specify wich mailbox to deeplink to ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following URL format and it worked for me. Of course, you can customized the link with HTML elements.

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/?ItemID=[Message ID]&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem&path=&exvsurl=1
```

You can read more on other formats in this [Stack Exchange post](https://superuser.com/questions/1503128/link-to-microsoft-outlook-365-webmail-email/1572112#1572112)

[image]

Comment: Just confirming - you tested that URL on a shared mailbox?  I am getting the message `The attachment couldn't be opened`, and then the browser tab closes.

Comment: Yes, I tested with a Shared mail as we already have a process to extract emails from that box and save them into SPO library. Can you try without attachment first? Will retest and let you know

Comment: I just retested with attachments and it worked for me. Email with attachments were sent to a **Shared** mail box from the outlook desktop client and then MS flow sends an email with that particular email link passing **Message Id**, and now clicking on the link, the email was opened in the outlook online. When I use **Conversation Id**, I get *The attachment couldn't be opened*

Answer (score 0):

I have found a relatively non-technical work around for this question after a lot of trial and error. I save alot of emails in OneNote, and in older versions of One Note, you can drag and drop specific emails to be saved on the page. But this isn't possible in OneNote 365 (to my knowledge).

However, I have found that I can save a print out of the email in OneNote, and then copy and paste the hyperlink to the specific email in the outlook webmail interface. However, the trick/work-around as far as I can tell, is that the email CANNOT be still in the inbox, but must have been moved to a different folder. If it remains in the inbox when you copy-and-paste the hyperlink, when you click on it, it will just open the inbox, instead of opening the specific email you want. This works for me in both Chrome and Edge, I hope others also find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

for a shared mailbox, this url works
[https://outlook.office.com/mail/yoursharedmailbox@mail;com/deeplink?ItemID=[itemid]&exvsurl=1](https://outlook.office.com/mail/yoursharedmailbox@mail;com/deeplink?ItemID=%5Bitemid%5D&exvsurl=1)

open a new window with the mail inside

just make sure to URL Encode the [itemid] you got with the email proprety and make sure also to replace  '-' and '_' wich are not supported

trying now to open a conversation using its Id...

Comment: I was also looking for a direct link to a shared mailbox, example:

https://outlook.office.com/mail/yoursharedmailbox@your.domain.com/